# running .ui file in qt creator

Tags: qt, qt4

I created a widget in Qt designer. After generating .ui file , now I want to compile it in qt creator. The .ui file is opened but run, build, debug .etc button are not enabled. How can I run this in qt creator? Creating a project and pasting .ui file into the project directory doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ui file must be added to the `FORMS` section of the .pro file.

```
FORMS+=yourfile.ui
```

The build step uses the `/bin/uic` command in the Qt directory (so you could conceivably do this manually from the command line outside of the IDE) to convert the .ui into a .h and a .cpp file (`yourfile.ui` becomes `ui_yourfile.h`).

Comment: this needs more info. any reference?

Comment: @greendino Sorry, I haven't used Qt since about this timeframe.  It may have changed since version 3 or 4.

Comment: (This was for the C++ version which may be why the syntax and info doesn't fit in with what you're expecting)